# Twilio (for KDDI) 自動応答時の かかった金額の取得の仕方

Tags: php

Twilio for KDDIでProgramable Voiceを使用して自動応答を行った際、
通話終了後に今の通話にかかった費用を取得する方法を調べています。
　
【試したこと】
　
Twilioの設定画面より通話ステータス変化時で設定したURLに受け取ったPOSTから、TwilioのログAPIを叩いてPriceを取得。

```
$twilio = new Client($AccountSid, $token);
$call = $twilio->calls($CallSid)->fetch();
echo $call->duration; // 通話時間
echo $call->price; // 通話料金
```

こちらを実行した所、通話時間は取れましたが、通話料金が取れない時があることが分かりました。
何か他に通話にかかった料金を取得する方法はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilioサポートから、サーバの状態でログへの反映に時間がかかる時があるそうです。
Twilioのログから料金を取得するのは一覧で表示したい時等で、通話終了後のStatusCallbackの際に
必要な場合は、Durationから自前で計算する必要がありそうです。